# Is it possible for  $R^2$ of a regression on two variables be higher than the sum of $R^2$ for two regressions on the individual variables?

Tags: regression, least-squares

In OLS, is it possible for the $R^2$ of a regression on two variables be higher than the sum of $R^2$ for two regressions on the individual variables.

$R^2(Y \sim A  + B) > R^2(Y \sim A) + R^2(Y \sim B) $

Edit: Ugh, this is trivial; that's what I get for trying to problems issues that I thought of while at the gym.  Sorry for wasting time again.  The answer is clearly yes.

$ Y \sim N(0,1)$

$ A \sim N(0,1)$

$ B  = Y - A $

$R^2(Y \sim A + B) = 1$, clearly.  But $R^2(Y \sim A)$ should be 0 in the limit and $R^2 (Y \sim B)$ should be 0.5 in the limit.

Comment: Are you asking about the inequality in the display equation (involving *residual sum of squares*) or are you asking about an inequality involving the sentence preceding that equation, i.e., involving $R^2$, the coefficient of determination?

Comment: I was interested in $R^2$; edited to fix the problem.

Comment: **Good**. There are nice geometric explanations of too.

Comment: You might edit out your answer and put it as an actual answer, so that the question doesn't remain "unanswered".

Comment: Any chance we could get an intuitive answer for this? if $R^2$ is percent of variance explained, then how can one explain more of the variance with the full model, than with a dedicated model for each variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a little bit of R that sets a random seed that will result in a dataset that shows it in action.

```
set.seed(103)

d <- data.frame(y=rnorm(20, 0, 1),
                a=rnorm(20, 0, 1),
                b=rnorm(20, 0, 1))

m1 <- lm(y~a, data=d)
m2 <- lm(y~b, data=d)
m3 <- lm(y~a+b, data=d)

r2.a <- summary(m1)[["r.squared"]]
r2.b <- summary(m2)[["r.squared"]]
r2.sum <- summary(m3)[["r.squared"]]

r2.sum > r2.a + r2.b
```

Not only is it possible (as you've already shown analytically) it's not hard to do. Given 3 normally distributed variables, it seems to happen about 40% of the time.

Comment: Wow. You MIT guys must have more time than commonly assumed ;-)

Comment: I was stuck in a long day of meetings. :)

Answer (score -1):

It isn't possible.  Moreover, if A and B are correlated at all (if their *r* is nonzero), the rsq of the regression on both will be less than the sum of their individual regressions' rsq's.

Note that even if A and B are completely uncorrelated, *adjusted* rsq's (which penalize for a low case-to-predictor ratio) may be slightly different between the two solutions.

Maybe you'd like to share more about the empirical evidence that's got you crossed up.

Comment: You might want to rethink this. Or, try a simulation. :)

Comment: Note that it is exactly when $A$ and $B$ **are** highly correlated that one **does** see the inequality stated in the question. :)

Comment: Consider the following extreme scenario, in which I'll use the more conventional $X_1$ and $X_2$ instead of $A$ and $B$. Take a (latent) bivariate normal distribution. Let $Y$ be the projection of the bivariate normal onto the eigenvector with largest eigenvalue. Let $X_1$ be the projection onto the eigenvector of the smallest eigenvalue. For any $0 < \rho < 1$, let $X_2 = \rho Y + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} X$. Then, the $R^2$ for $X_1$ is zero and the $R^2$ for $X_2$ can be made arbitrarily small. But, the $R^2$ of $X_1+X_2$ is *always* 1 (why?). Perhaps, you could consider editing your post.

Comment: ...and by $X_1 + X_2$ I mean the model that incorporates both predictors, not their actual sum. A better notation would probably be via the direct sum $X_1 \oplus X_2$.